# Change image source attribute for button when clicking itself as well as other buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project where I need to toggle images of a set of buttons on clicking each one. The functionality I need is as follows:

Image gots from `arrow-down.png` to `arrow-up.png` when I click one button.

If image is already toggled to `arrow-up.png` for one button, then clicking another toggles all other button images to `arrow-down.png` and toggles its own image to `arrow-up.png`.

Also if one image is already toggled to `button-up.png`, clicking itself toggles its own image back to `button-down.png`.

So far, I've got the first two requirements done, whereby the images toggle when a button is first clicked, and when another button is clicked.

I'm sutck with the third requirement, where clicking itself toggles its own image.

My html and jquery are as follows:

```
<button class="btn p-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn-1">
    <p class="text_small text-capitalize font-weight-bold">button 1</p>
    <img src="img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-down.png" alt="" class="img-fluid btn-toggle btn-down">
</button>
<button class="btn p-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#btn-2">
    <p class="text_small text-capitalize font-weight-bold">button 2</p>
    <img src="img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-down.png" alt="" class="img-fluid btn-toggle btn-down">
</button>



$('.btn').click(function () {
    $('.btn-toggle').removeClass('btn-up');
    $('.btn-toggle').addClass('btn-down');
    $('.btn-toggle').attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-down.png');

    $(this).find('.btn-toggle').removeClass('btn-down');
    $(this).find('.btn-toggle').addClass('btn-up');
    $(this).find('.btn-toggle').attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-up.png');
})
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share your html/css too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some conditional check before applying the classes and attributes.

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var isPrevActive = $(this).find('.btn-toggle').hasClass('btn-up');

    // Clear all
    $('.btn-toggle').removeClass('btn-up');
    $('.btn-toggle').addClass('btn-down');
    $('.btn-toggle').attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-down.png');

    if (!isPrevActive) {
        $(this).find('.btn-toggle').removeClass('btn-down');
        $(this).find('.btn-toggle').addClass('btn-up');
        $(this).find('.btn-toggle').attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-up.png');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering

> I want to change the source attribute of the image with the .btn-toggle class on clicking the button, so that the button essentially flips to the open position when clicked, and flips back to the closed position when I click either the same button or other buttons in the set.

Run a condition checking the buttons state

```
 $('.btn').click(function () {
    var button = $(this);
    if(button.hasClass('btn-up')){
        button.removeClass('btn-up')
        .addClass('btn-down')
        .attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-down.png');
    }else{
        button.removeClass('btn-down')
        .addClass('btn-up')
        .attr('src', 'img/img-pages/events-page/arrow-up.png');
    }
})
```